# XSLT create element in order when sibling elements arbitrarily exist?

Tags: xml, xslt

Suppose you have a element with a content model as follows:

```xml
<!ELEMENT wrapper (a*,b*,c*,d*,e*,f*,g*,h*,i*,j*,k*,l*,m*,n*,o*,p*,q*,r*,s*,t*,u*,v*,w*,x*,y*,z*)>
```

In other words, within a wrapper element there is a specified order of child elements which may arbitrarily exist.

You need to create a new element (e.g. m) within the wrapper whilst preserving what was already there and ensuring that the output conforms to the content model.

This is sort of a solution:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:sequence select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wrapper">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m"/>
    <m>This is new</m>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

However, this solution will drop all whitespace, comments, or processing instructions within the wrapper element. I've come up with some solutions that don't drop those things but none that I'm happy with.

What's the most elegant solution to this problem that won't drop nodes? XSLT 3 and schema-aware solutions are fine.

Here are some example inputs and outputs:

```
<!-- Input -->
<wrapper/>

<!-- Output -->
<wrapper><m>This is new</m></wrapper>

<!-- Input -->
<wrapper><a/><z/></wrapper>

<!-- Output -->
<wrapper><a/><m>This is new</m><z/></wrapper>

<!-- Input -->
<wrapper><m/></wrapper>

<!-- Output -->
<wrapper><m/><m>This is new</m></wrapper>

<!-- Input -->
<wrapper>
  <a/>
  <!-- put m here -->
  <z/>
</wrapper>

<!-- Output -->
<!-- NB: The comment and whitespace could come after the inserted element instead. This case is ambiguous -->
<wrapper>
  <a/>
  <!-- put m here --><m>This is new</m>
  <z/>
</wrapper>

<!-- Input -->
<wrapper>
  <a/>
  <b/>
  <c/>
  <n/>
  <o/>
  <!-- p is not here -->
  <?do not drop this?>
</wrapper>

<!-- Output -->
<wrapper>
  <a/>
  <b/>
  <c/><m>This is new</m>
  <n/>
  <o/>
  <!-- p is not here -->
  <?do not drop this?>
</wrapper>
```

It's not critical that non-element nodes around the inserted element come before or after, just that they aren't dropped and their order with respect to the original elements is preserved.

Comment: You could instruct the template/s matching the child elements to copy any trailing (or leading) text, comment, or processing instruction nodes. -- P.S. A [mcve] could be useful here.

Comment: @Danielhaley `m` might not exist as I understand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wrapper">
    <xsl:variable name="all" select="node()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="middle" select="(n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z)[1]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="if($middle) then count($all[. &lt;&lt; $middle]) else count($all)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="new">
        <m>This is new</m>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="insert-before($all, $i+1, $new) "/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:template match="wrapper">
    <xsl:variable name="all" select="node()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="middle" select="(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m)[last()]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="if($middle) then index-of($all/generate-id(), generate-id($middle)) else 0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="new">
        <m>This is new</m>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="insert-before($all, $i+1, $new) "/>
    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>
```